# How to create a custom author page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How can I create a custom author page in WordPress?

Such as I want my authors url would be `/author/author-id`

I've tried it on localhost many times but failed every time.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-author-link-structure/

This plugin will change your author url to /author/author-id exactly as you want.

Regards

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add new User like: [image]

[image]

Comment: My question wasn't that look like you haven't understand...

Comment: Follow This link, I hope This will help you http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-a-custom-author-profile-page-to-your-wordpress/